# Load arguments before calling Flask Manager command

Tags: python, argparse, flask-script

I need to add some preconfig params to setup app before running manager's run method and I need to get them using arguments. Once, I get them run_app will do the rest.

My issue here is the following: the only way to pass arguments to manager is to add them to the run command function which is executed after run_app call. Adding a argument interface with argparse before run_app execution doesn't work either, because it causes a conflict error with flask's manager. Do you know of any approach I could take to solve this problem?

```
from flask_script import Manager
from app_file import run_app

#get params here
app = run_app(params)
manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def routes():
    print(app.url_map)

@manager.command
def run(debug=True):
    routes()
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc', debug=debug, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

I'm running the app by calling `python manager run`

Thanks for the help :-)